# Unable to Edit Styles with One-to-Many Relation in Prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm encountering difficulties editing styles and sub-categories in my Next.js application using Prisma as the ORM. I have a one-to-many relationship between a sub-category and styles. While I'm able to delete both the sub-category and styles, I'm struggling with editing them.

**Database Schema:**

Here are my Prisma models:

```
model SubCategory {
  id          String    @id @default(uuid())
  name        String
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
  store_id    String
  category_id String
  category    Category  @relation("CategoryToSubCategory", fields: [category_id], references: [id])
  styles      Style[]   @relation("SubCategoryToStyles")

  @@index([category_id])
}

model Style {
  id             String      @id @default(uuid())
  name           String
  createdAt      DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime    @updatedAt
  store_id       String
  subcategory_id String
  subcategory    SubCategory @relation("SubCategoryToStyles", fields: [subcategory_id], references: [id])

  @@index([subcategory_id])
}
```

**API Routes:**

I have implemented PATCH and DELETE routes to handle editing and deleting sub-categories and styles:

```
export async function PATCH(
    req: Request, 
    { params }: { params: { store_id: string, subcategory_id: string } }
    ) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body: SubCategoryRequest = await req.json();
    const { name, category_id, styles } = body;

    ...

    const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: params.store_id,
        userId,
      },
    });
    
    const updatedSubCategory = await prismadb.subCategory.update({
      where: {
        id: params.subcategory_id,
      },
      data: {
        name,
        category_id,
        styles: {
          deleteMany: {},
          createMany: {
            data: styles.map((style_name: string) => ({
              name: style_name,
              store_id: params.store_id,
            })),
          },
        },
      },
      include: {
        styles: true,
      },
    });
    
    return NextResponse.json(updatedSubCategory);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('[SUBCATEGORY_PATCH]', error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
  }
}

export async function DELETE(
    req: Request, 
    { params }: { params: { store_id: string, subcategory_id: string, style_name: string } }
    ) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status: 401 });
    }
    ...

    const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: params.store_id,
        userId,
      },
    });

    if (!storeByUserId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorised", { status: 403 });
    }

    const SubCategoryAndStyles = await deleteSubCategoryAndStyles(params.subcategory_id);

    return NextResponse.json(SubCategoryAndStyles);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('[SUBCATEGORY_DELETE]', error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
  }
}

async function deleteSubCategoryAndStyles(subcategoryId: string) {
  
  await prismadb.style.deleteMany({
    where: {
      subcategory_id: subcategoryId,
    },
  });

  await prismadb.subCategory.deleteMany({
    where: {
      id: subcategoryId,
    },
  });

  return { message: "Sub-Category and associated Styles deleted successfully." };
}
```

**Issue:**

When attempting to edit a style, I'm unable to successfully update the database. While I can delete them without issues, editing seems to encounter some hurdles.

**Client-side Component:**

I have a React component for editing styles (`StyleEditModal`), but despite fetching the style details, I'm unable to properly update them. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
interface StyleEditModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    style: string;
    onClose: () => void;
    onConfirm: (editedStyle: string) => void;
    loading: boolean;
}

export const StyleEditModal: React.FC<StyleEditModalProps> = ({
    isOpen,
    style,
    onClose,
    onConfirm,
    loading
}) => {

    const params = useParams();
    const [editedStyle, setEditedStyle] = useState(style);

    const handleConfirm = () => {
        onConfirm(editedStyle);
        onClose();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpen) {
            fetchStyleDetails();
            setEditedStyle(style)
        }
    }, [isOpen, style]);

    const fetchStyleDetails = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/${params.store_id}/sub-categories/${params.subcategory_id}`); 
            console.log('Sub-Category Response:', response.data.styles);
            console.log('Sub-Category Response:', response.data.styles.forEach((style:any) => {
              console.log('Style Name:', style.name);
          }));
            const existing_style = response.data.styles;
            setEditedStyle(existing_style.name);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching style details:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Modal
            title="Edit Style"
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClose={onClose}
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`${style}`}
                value={editedStyle || ''}
                onChange={(e) => setEditedStyle(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div>
                <Button
                    type="button"
                    disabled={loading} 
                    variant="outline"
                    onClick={onClose}
                >
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button
                    type="button"
                    disabled={loading} 
                    variant="default"
                    onClick={handleConfirm}
                >
                    Save
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

When editing a style, I expect the changes to be reflected in the database. This includes updating the name of the style. However, despite efforts, the changes are not being saved to the database. I'm unsure what is causing this issue.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

`console.log('Sub-Category Response:', response.data.styles)` displays the styles in an array. However, the `console.log('Sub-Category Response:', response.data.styles.forEach((style:any) => {console.log('Style Name:', style.name);}));` response is undefined, suggesting that there might be an issue with how to access the response data.

I've debugged the code and reviewed the Prisma documentation, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly implement the editing functionality for styles in my Next.js application using Prisma.

Comment: I was approach debugging from a different perspective: instead of logging the server response, I would log the actual SQL statements PrismaClient makes. One way to do it is:

`const prisma = new PrismaClient({ log: [ { emit: "event", level: "query",}] });

prisma.$on("query", async (e) => { console.log(e.query, e.params)});`